# Why does the compiler say that the variable "z" is redeclared as a different variable type?

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, declaration

I'm beginning learning how to use functions in c, I was trying to create a function to divide integers but the compiler gives me an error. I searched over google which lead me to here where the question is asked frequently but I didn't understand what the error is exactly. So, I'm re-posting it.

Notice that the problem according to the compiler is on "z not "div".

Here is the code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

float div(int x, int z);
void main()
{
  int n,m;
  float div;
  printf("Enter first number: \n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter second number: \n");
  scanf("%d",m);
  if(m!=0)
  {
    div=div(n,m);
    printf("%d/%d=%f \n",n,m,div);
  }
}

float div(int x, int z)
{
  int x,z;
  float div;

  if(z!=0){
    div=x/z;
    return div;
  }

}
```

Comment: `div` is now a function and a float.

Comment: Even when I edit "div" and make it say, divee, the problem occurs. In fact, the compiler says that the problem is with z not div.

Comment: The parameters of your `div` function are `x` and `z`, but you declare to local variables of the same name, which you can't. The function parameters are local variables passed in from outside. They have to exist alongside all other local variables without name clashes.

Comment: `div()` does not return a value when `y==0` (where I think you meant to write `if (z!=0)`). What value do you think should be returned? Or should more drastic action be taken?

Comment: Please change your second `scanf` to `scanf("%d", &m)`, with the address operator `&`. (You got it right two lines above that.)

Comment: The second issue that Simeon Visser has already told you about is that the local variable `div` shadows the function `div`. It is legal to have a local variable and a function of the same name, but while the local is in scope, you cannot access thze function.

Comment: @MOehm, I've edited the scand, Do you mean I have to change x,y into n,m? Does that what you mean? I've already changed div "the variable " to other name, the same problem occurs.

Comment: I think that you don't need the two local variables `x` and `z` at all. Use the two parameters for your calculation.

Comment: @learner: Good. Many people have posted long and detailed answers along the same lines. Please accept one of them.

Comment: @MOehm, I will make sure I'll. I was just reading all of them before accepting one. that's all.

Comment: @learner Also if you didn't already saw it, here is a quick tour though the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a few things wrong:

(From the comments of BLUEPIXY, Also you should avoid the name div, since a few standard library's use it)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Prototypes*/
float divve(int x, int z);
    //^^^^^ Changed name of the function since you have a float variable with the same name in main

int main() {
//^ Default return type of main is int

    int n, m;
    float div;

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
              //^ You forgot the address operator here

    if(m != 0) {
        div = divve(n, m);
        printf("%d/%d=%f \n", n, m, div);
    }

    return 0;
  //^^^^^^^^^ Return to end the program nicely 

}

float divve(int x, int z) {

    //Removed second declaration of x and z
    float div;

    if(z != 0){
     //^ Changed y to z since you don't have a y variable in the function | BTW Also you already checked if m is != 0 in the main function
        div = (float)x / (float)z;
        return div;
    }

    return 0;
  //^^^^^^^^^ return something if the if statement fails

}
```

Comment: `div` must be avoided because some in the standard library function name. also `x / z` --> `(float)x / z`;

Comment: @BLUEPIXY jeah, thanks for the notice (casted both int's to make it really clear)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Why is it (float)x/y not just x/y?

Comment: @learner Just try it yourself and you will see it! `3/5 (x/y) -> 0.0` | `3/5 ((float)x /y) -> 0.6`

Comment: @learner This is necessary in order to `1/2` the `0.5` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
float div(int x, int z)
{ //                 ^
    int x,z; // << Two 'z's
    float div;

    if(y!=0){
        div=((float)x) / z; // Add a cast to avoid integer division
        return div;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is already a `z` in the scope within `div`, so the second declaration (the local variable) conflicts with the first one (the formal parameter of the function).

Note that I added a `return` statement for the case when `y` is zero. This would avoid undefined behavior when control reaches the end of a non-void function.

Also note that it is a good idea to avoid naming variables and functions with the same identifier, so it is a good idea to rename `div` variable in your `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring variables with the same names as the function parameters in the function `div`.

But there are more problems, enumerating them in the order of appearance

1. You named your function `div()` and then declared a variable with the same name in `main()` to store the return value of the function.
2. Your second `scanf()` is missing the `&`, I assume that was a typo.
3. You declared `x` and `z` in the `div()` function which aare the names of the arguments of the function, then you test for `y == 0` which is not declared anywhere.
4. You divide the integers and that will truncate the result if for example `z > x` to `0`.
5. You exit the `div()` function, in case `z == 0` without returning any value, you might return `0`, or any meaningful value that indicates that the operation could not be performed.

I fixed your code, here it is

```
float divide(int x, int z);

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    float quotient;

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    if (m != 0)
    {
        quotient = divide(n,m);
        printf("%d/%d = %f \n", n, m, quotient);
    }
}

float divide(int x, int z)
{
    float result;

    if (z != 0) {
        result = (float)x / (float)z;
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should give meaningful names to your variables, that improves readability and avoids this kind of problem completely.

See how I renamed the `div()` function to a more expressive name `divide()`, and the return value in it *"which is not strictly needed"*, i named it `result` to reflect that the result of computations will go in it, and in `main()` the return value of `divide()` a called it `qoutient` to also let the reader expect where it might come from without seeing the line where you assign to it.